# MySql join two tables for comma separated values in both columns

Tags: mysql, database, join

I want join T1 and T2 on the basis of comma seperated values (1,4,6) in T1 and (4,6,8) in T2.

If any single element of T1 is matching to any Single element of T2, the row should fetched.

Comment: This is difficult to do in MySQL (and most databases).  You should consider normalizing your tables and do away with that CSV data.

Comment: You can use `FIND_IN_SET` for the right side of the join condition, but you will need a trick to explode the CSV on the left side.

Comment: I am already using FIND_IN_SET, But I want to know how to explode the left side data.

Comment: Trust me, you don't want to be doing this.  Change your database design and avoid much suffering.

Comment: Thanks,It was my last attempt to solve the issue, But now I will have to change the database design.

Comment: If `T1` were not in CSV, your question would be manageable.  But CSV on both sides is really ugly.

Comment: CSV on either side is ugly (to the relational db) it may make sense in your head but not at all to the db. Do what your conscience is already telling you.... normalize the tables